# Closing a served file in clojure/webnoir

Tags: clojure, noir

I've got the following function in webnoir that serves up an image from disk.

```
(defpage [:get "/GetPhoto"] {:keys [photoName]}
         (def file (io/input-stream  (str photoName ".jpg")))
         (resp/set-headers {"Content-Type" "image/jpeg"} file))
```

I assume I should close the file, but when I add `(.close file)` to the end of the function, I get an error `java.io.IOException: Stream closed` when accessing the URL.  What's the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you can't close the file at the end of the function, because all you do with noir/ring is to return a data structure describing the response. Ring then uses this data structure to actually respond to the client. In this case it sees a stream and tries to read from it. When you close it (explicit or with `with-open`) this will fail.

I would expect you don't have to do anything and ring will close the stream after exhausting it.

You don't want nested `def`. You don't want nested `def`. You don't want nested `def`. You don't want...

Comment: Cool, I had a feeling the inner def smelled bad.  I'll change it to let syntax (or just remove the variable completely) ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

The def on line two is very likely not what you want. I would recommend replacing it with a `with-open` statement. This is defining a new symbol for the whole namespace each time this function runs. As a general rule calls to `def` are used at the top level or inside a macro.

```
(defpage [:get "/GetPhoto"] {:keys [photoName]}
         (with-open [file (io/input-stream  (str photoName ".jpg"))]
           (resp/set-headers {"Content-Type" "image/jpeg"} file))
```

Comment: "standing-over-the-shoulder effect". I could have *sworn* I tried this and got the same IOException, but now it works.  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: No, wait, now I'm getting the IOException again.